# What is this anime about a virtual reality world with no pain?

Tags: megazone-23

I'm looking for an anime that involves a teenage boy who enters a virtual reality world, like the rest of Tokyo. The virtual realty world entered did not have pain, so players could be hurt and not feel anything.

In the story, first he is on a bike that gets into a car accident and the bike is beyond repair. Later, he finds a credit card that uses all three types of currencies in the world. The card has no owner and seems to "hack" the systems. A girl is on a roof and sees the boy "steal" her card. The boy finds a hungry girl and buys her food with the card. A police officer sees the boy purchasing food with a lot of money and sees the card. The police officer attacks the boy.

Does anyone know what this anime is?

Comment: Do you know approximately when you saw this anime, or its art style, or perhaps the appearance of any of the characters?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I've never seen the show myself, but it sounds a lot like the show [Megazone 23](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megazone_23), which is about a virtual world run by a supercomputer that exists as a modern day (to us, the story is set in the future) Tokyo.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for "OZ" where the world is faced with problems in reality so sleep capsules were created that enter people into a virtual reality so society can keep moving. (Action  Comedy  Drama  Sci-fi  Seinen). OZ (TOKIYA Seigo) is prob what you are looking for since he gits hit by a car while on a bike ad complains about having to buy another.